# invalid convertion in std::accumulate

Tags: c++, c++11, accumulate, stdarray

I have a class representing a point in `N` dimensions with a `min` static function (minimum field by field)

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class Point : public std::array<T,N>
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Point(Args&&... args) : std::array<T,N>{{args...}} {}

    // ...

    static Point min(const Point&, const Point&) {
        // ...  
    }
};
```

Everything works well when I write

```
Point<float,3> a = {0.f, 1.f, 2.f};
Point<float,3> b = {2.f, 1.f, 0.f};
Point<float,3> c = Point<float,3>::min(a,b); // OK
```

But if I try to use `std::accumulate` over an array

```
Point<float,3> array[100] = ... ;
Point<float,3> min = std::accumulate(array, array+100, array[0], Point<float,3>::min); // Error
```

I get an error :

```
error: cannot convert ‘Point<float, 3ul>’ to ‘float’ in initialization
adimx::Point<T,N>::Point(Args&&... args) : std::array<T,N>{{args...}}
```

Is this an issue with `std::accumulate` implementation not being compatible with my constructor ?

Comment: That variadic constructor is hijacking the copy constructor call. Constrain it.

Comment: @T.C. That maes sens. How do I constrain it ?

Comment: @Amxx specify copy constructor implicitly: `Point(const Point &) = default;`

Comment: T.C. says is right.  Forwarding reference produces a better match for a copy-ctor call, hence it gets selected by the overload resolution. Copy-ctor is still generated for this class. It doesn't have to be explicitly defaulted (user-declared)

Comment: You're double-counting `array[0]`. If you use `array[0]` as the initial value, start accumulating at `array+1`. Alternatively, use `Point<float,3>(0,0,0)` as the initial value.

Comment: I have an ugly solution. Remove Args's && .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New solution:

```
template <bool J>
using disable_if=enable_if<!J>;

template <typename T,typename... Tail> struct getHead
{
    typedef typename decay<T>::type type;
};

template<typename... Args,typename = typename disable_if<is_same<typename getHead<Args...>::type,Point<T,N> >::value >::type >
    Point(Args&&... args) : std::array<T,N> {{args...}}
    {
        //...
    }
```

I believe this solution is perfect.We stop forwarding reference variable parameter constructor only when parameter is Point itself.Any other type still call forwarding reference variable parameter constructor.
No matter `Point<float,3>` or `Point<int,3>` or `Point<int,2>` or `Point<user-define,numx>`it always OK.

---

There are at least three solutions for you to choose.

**First**, in order to avoid forwarding reference variable parameter constructor hijacked the copy constructor, so removal of this function, instead of

```
template<typename... Args>
        Point(Args... args) : std::array<T,N> {{args...}} {}//remove &&
```

this solution is to avoid problems instead of solving the problem.

**Second**, as TC said, stop forwarding reference variable parameter constructor hijacked constructor, as long as when all types all fit when enabled. This way is more complex, but also weaken the application scope of your template.

**Third**, as MSalters said, change `array[0]` to `Point<float,3>(0,0,0)`,

```
Point<float,3> min = std::accumulate(array, array+100, Point<float,3>(0,0,0), Point<float,3>::min);
```

**It is OK,but why?**

**As n4260 12.9 31.3 C++ Standrad says:**

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference
>   (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same
>   cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by 
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
>   omitted copy/move

So accumulate directly call `Point` constructor with three float ,doesn't call copy constructor.**So doesn't call forwarding reference variable parameter constructor pass a Point Object as a parameter**,this is where your compile error.

Drawback is that every time you use the `accumulate` function require incoming rvalues, and cannot be an lvalue.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to constrain that constructor, so that it participates in overload resolution only if all arguments are implicitly convertible to `float`:

```
template<bool... > class bool_pack;
template<bool... b>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, b...>, bool_pack<b..., true>>;

template<typename... Args,
         class = typename std::enable_if<all_true<std::is_convertible<Args, float>::value...>::value>::type>
Point(Args&&... args) : std::array<T,N>{{args...}} {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the constructor wins by overload resolution, you can provide defaulted versions of the needed constructors:

```
Point(Point&) = default;
Point(const Point&) = default;
Point(Point&&) = default;
Point& operator=(const Point&) = default;
```

Comment: Sorry,you are wrong.Forwarding reference produces a better match for a copy-ctor call, hence it gets selected by the overload resolution. Copy-ctor is still generated for this class. It doesn't have to be explicitly defaulted (user-declared)